# Flutter screen height issue

Tags: flutter

I have issue my screen showing orange line in end and show ing error of A Renderflex overflowed by 5105 pixels on the bottom .

My code

```
class Orderlist extends StatelessWidget {
  final posts;

  Orderlist({Key key, this.posts}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double stackWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double stackHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          test(),
          test(),
          test(),
          test(),
          test()
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

}

class test extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Container(
      color: Color(0xfff6f6f6),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(14.0),
        child: Card(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
          ),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: Container(
                  color: Color(0xfff8f8f8),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment:
                          CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text(
                              'asdada',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontFamily: 'SFPROBOLD',
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  fontSize: 16,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                            Text(
                               'asda'
                                    .toString(),
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 14))
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: Container(
                            width: width * 0.13,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Color(0xffef9500),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                    Radius.circular(5))),
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                              child: Center(
                                  child: Text('Pending',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontFamily: 'SFPROBOLD',
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                          fontSize: 9))),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(13.0),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        child: Text(
                          'Delivery',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: 'SFPROBOLD',
                              color: Color(0xffea6c7b),
                              fontSize: 13),
                        ),
                      ),

                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment:
                      MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          child: Text(
                            'asdada',
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                          ),
                        ),
                        IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.arrow_forward,
                            color: Colors.grey,
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {
                            // do something
                            Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) =>
                                      OrderDetails()),
                            );
                          },
                        )
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Try to wrap the first widget with SingleScrollview but its not working. Also try to wrap the Listviewbuilder but still showing pixels error and if i wrap SignleScrollview with expanded then its showing parent directory error

Comment: can you edit and add some static data in your post list. Because i'm not getting any pixel overflow.

Comment: @ArpitAwasthi i have added it maybe your are not getting error because you show the box one time when i show its in static multiple time then its showing error

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is because you wrapped the column in `ListView` as well as `SingleChildScrollView`. Try removing any one of them.

Comment: Try but still not working i have updated my code with static data also now

Comment: just return Test() to check if there is an error in the Test class, also try reducing the hight and width to 3/4